# Android horizontal scroll menu (like in google locations)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-menu

I would like to implement a menu like in the google locations app.

It looks like horizontal slide menu but image slides left if you move pointer right.
onClick event trigered just after finger release without additional click

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: you can try and use JakeWarton's `ViewPagerIndicator` with a `Pager`

Answer (score 1):

Create a horizontal `LinearLayout` and add to it your desired clickable `ImageView`s.
Finally wrap all of this in a `HorizontalScrollView`, Like this (this example is with buttons):

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bar_edit"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button1_all"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onTasksListFilterButtonPressed"
                android:text="@string/all"
                android:textColor="@color/my_black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bWaiting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button2_pending"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onTasksListFilterButtonPressed"
                android:text="@string/waiting"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bInProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button3_in_progress"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onTasksListFilterButtonPressed"
                android:text="@string/inprogress"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bOnTheWay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button4_on_the_way"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onTasksListFilterButtonPressed"
                android:text="@string/ontheway"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bComplete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button5_complete"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onTasksListFilterButtonPressed"
                android:text="@string/complete"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bFailed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button6_failed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onTasksListFilterButtonPressed"
                android:text="@string/failed"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: yes but this horizontal scrollview works in different way i`m asking
just run google locations app and check how it works is hard to describe its behaviour in foto

Comment: I'm not familiar with that app, and have no idea how it works.